# How to prove $x^{n}$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-continuity

How to prove $x^{n}$ is not uniformly continuous on the interval $[0, +\infty)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$?

Comment: Presumably you mean for $n>1$.

Comment: Have you tried something? Welcome to MSE :) What about $n$? Is it an integer? Is it $\ge 0$, $\ge 1$, we don't know.

Comment: Maybe you can look at a related question: [Showing a function is not uniformly continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135234/showing-a-function-is-not-uniformly-continuous)

Comment: Look at $(x+\delta)^n-x^n$.

Comment: n is integer and n > 1. I know how to prove when n = 2. proof it by contradiction when n = 2.

    f(x) = x^{2}

`x_{1}=\sqrt{n},x_{2}=\sqrt{n+2},for \varepsilon = 1 
I get |x_{1}-x_{2}|=\frac{1}{{\sqrt{n}}+{\sqrt{n+2}}} \to 0
but |f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})| = 2 > 1`

but how would I chose the sequence when n > 2?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Is it enough to prove, that $f_n(x)=x^n$ not uniformly continuous on $E=[0,1] \subseteq [0,\infty)$ and then conclude that, $f_n(x)=x^n$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Is it true that, if $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $E\subseteq D $, then  $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $D$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: @SalechAlhasov It would be sufficient to show this for a subset. But $[0,1]$ is not a good choice for this particular case. A continuous function on a compact set (compact space) is uniformly continuous, see e.g. [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Heine-Cantor_Theorem) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yes, forgot that *little detail*. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to show that there exists **some** $\epsilon>0$ such that there is **no** $\delta>0$ for which
$$|x-y|<\delta\implies |x^n-y^n|<\epsilon.$$
Try $\epsilon=1$. Thus you want to show that for **any** $\delta>0$, there is **some** pair $x,y\in [0,\infty)$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ yet $|x^n-y^n|\geq 1$. Let's try letting $x=y+\delta/2$. Then we have $|x-y|=\delta/2<\delta$ and 
$$|x^n-y^n|=(y+\delta/2)^n-y^n\geq (y+\delta/2)y^{n-1}-y^n=\delta/2\cdot y^{n-1}.$$
Can you find some $y$ such that $\delta/2\cdot y^{n-1}$ is at least $1$?

Comment: Thank you, I know how to do next.

Comment: @Mobius, have you interested(sure you do) upvoiting the given answer? You can do it by clicking on the arrow pointing forward.
And welcome to M.SE!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your choice of x? What made you think this x would work?

Comment: @alwaysiamcaesar, better question is finding $y.$ The choice of $x$ according to $y$ has been elaborated.

Answer (score 2):

**Proposition.** The function $x^n$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ for $n\in (1,+\infty)$.

---

*Proof 1.* Define sequences $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ by
$$x_k\mathrel{\mathop:}=k+\frac{1}{k^{n-1}},$$
$$y_k\mathrel{\mathop:}=k.$$
Then
$$x_k-y_k=\frac{1}{k^{n-1}}\to0 \text{ as }k\to\infty,$$
but
$$\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty }\left( x_{k}^{n} -y_{k}^{n}\right) =\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty } k^{n}\left[\left( 1+\frac{1}{k^{n}}\right)^{n} -1\right] =\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty } k^{n} \cdotp \frac{n}{k^{n}}  =n\ ,\ $$
showing $x^n$ to be not uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$.

---

*Proof 2.* Use the following proposition:

> If a real-valued function $f$ is differentiable on $(s,+\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\lvert f'(x)\rvert = +\infty$, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(s,+\infty)$.

A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405123/proof-that-a-function-whose-derivative-has-infinite-limit-is-not-uniformly-conti/2405159#2405159).

Comment: In the proposition of proof 2, you mean to say $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\lvert f'(x)\rvert = +\infty$ instead of $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\lvert f(x)\rvert = +\infty$ , as otherwise the identity function would be a trivial counterexample. I tried to edit it for you, but I'm unsure how this website works and I think mods need to approve my edit.

Comment: @mattematician Thanks! It turns out that the author can also approve edits.

Comment: ahh I see. Also, both of your proofs are very nice and very slick. I've never heard the second proposition before reading your answer -- very interesting

Answer (score 1):

We note that since we have freedom to choose an $\varepsilon>0$, we let $\varepsilon=1$. Therefore, we want to show that for some $x,y$ that $|x^n-y^n|<1$ does not arise from $|x-y|<\delta$.   For any $\delta>0$,
    if we let $x=\delta$ and $y=\frac{1}{2\delta}$, then 
    $$|x-y|=\delta-\frac{1}{2\delta}<\delta$$
    Then, 
    $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^n-y^n|=|\delta^n-\frac{1}{2^n\delta^n}|\geq 1$$
    for any $\delta$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.
    Therefore, since no $\delta$ can satisfy the uniform continuity condition for this $\varepsilon$, then we conclude that the function $f(x)=x^n$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: We use $y=1/2\delta$ because that avoids the issue of $\delta=1$ satisfying the less than $\varepsilon$ requirement. We are not saying the function is not continuous, just that it is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Why is $\delta^n-\frac{1}{2^n\delta^n} \geq 1$?

Comment: it isnt.  The absolute value is.  if $\delta$ is greater than 1, it is clear.  If it is less than one, write $(\delta^n2^n)$ as $(2\delta)^n$, and it is clear again that $|\delta^n-\frac{1}{2^n\delta^n}|\geq 1$