# Show that $f(x) = x^{p}$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ if $p > 1$ - Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

Show that $f(x) = x^{p}$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ if $p > 1$

**Attempt:**

Consider the sequences $$x_{n} = n + \frac{1}{n} \\ y_{n} = n$$

Examining these sequences we have:

$$|x_n - y_n| = |n + \frac{1}{n} - n| = \Bigg|\frac{1}{n}\Bigg| \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg|\frac{1}{n} \Bigg| = 0$$

But:

$$|f(x_{n}) - f(y_{n})| = \Bigg| (n + \frac{1}{n})^{p} - n^{p} \Bigg| = \Bigg|\sum_{k = 0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}n^{p-k}\Bigg(\frac{1}{n} \Bigg)^{k} - n^{p} \Bigg| \\ \Rightarrow \Bigg|\sum_{k = 1}^{p}\binom{p}{k}n^{p-k}\Bigg(\frac{1}{n} \Bigg)^{k} \Bigg| > p \ - used \ binomial \ thm \ and\ just\ subtracted\ the\ first\ term. $$

Therefore $f(x) = x^{p}$ is not uniformly continuous.

**Thoughts:**

I think I over complicated things by wanting to use $$\Bigg|\sum_{k = 1}^{p}\binom{p}{k}n^{p-k}\Bigg(\frac{1}{n} \Bigg)^{k} \Bigg| > p$$

In fact I probably have to prove such a claim, which I had difficulty doing by induction. I essentially just replicated the proof that would usually be used to show $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous over all of $\mathbb{R}$.If this is the right idea, what would be a way to establish that last inequality from the binomial theorem?

Comment: How do you evaluate your series for p=1.5?

Comment: @graeme....Hmmmm.......you have a good point there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $f(x)=x^p$ when $p=2$ what we do is the following.

Let $\epsilon=1$. Let $\delta >0$ be given. Now, let $x=\frac{1}{\delta}$ and $y=\frac{1}{\delta}+\frac{\delta}{2}$ in the common definition of uniformly continuous ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity)). Then, $$|x-y|=\frac{\delta}{2}<\delta.$$

But $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y||x+y|=|\frac{2}{\delta}+\frac{\delta}{2}|\frac{\delta}{2}> \frac{
2\delta}{\delta 2}=1=\epsilon.$$

Thus, $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous. Now, can you try with a general $p$?

Comment: So perhaps I chose the wrong sequences to show it's not uniformly continuous then....

Comment: I think it is easier to play with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ than with sequences.

Comment: I'm not sure if this factorization idea would work because $p$ doesn't have to be a natural number.

Comment: Same as: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181579/how-to-prove-xn-is-not-uniformly-continuous

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach.  $|x^p-y^p|\gt |x-y|x^{p-1}$ which is not bounded for $p\gt 1$.