# $f(x)=x^2$ is not Lipschitz?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Consider the function $\ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\ f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I think that $f$ is NOT Lipschitz (meaning, there exists no constant $c\in[0,\infty)$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$). Here is my proof:

Suppose that it IS Lipschitz. There there exists some constant $c\in[0,\infty)$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then:

$\implies\ \ \ \ |x^2-y^2|\leq c |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

$\implies\ \ \ \ |x-y| \cdot |x+y|\leq c |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

$\implies\ \ \ \ |x+y|\leq c$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

But there is no real number $c$ with the property that $|x+y|\leq c$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. This is a contradiction. $f$ is not Lipschitz.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Almost. The third implication requires you to assume that $x-y\ne 0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A shorter and more eloquent way to show it is not Lipschitz is fix $x$ at $0$, and consider a sequence tending to $\infty$, say, $\{n\}$, then
$$|f(n) - f(0)|/|n - 0| = n^2/n = n,$$
which cannot be bounded by any **fixed** Lipschitz constant $c$.

Answer (score 9):

Your proof is mostly correct but here is a shorter proof:

If $f$ were Lipschitz, then $f'$ would be bounded.

Comment: This is not true on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Proving that $f(x) = 6x^2$ is not uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478917/proving-that-fx-6x2-is-not-uniformly-continuous/2479008?s=2|14.0001#2479008) it is not uniformly continuous therefore it cannot be Lipschitz.

See this answer:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2479050