# Proving that $f(x) = 6x^2$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

The question is:

Prove $f(x) = 6x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on the interval $[2, \infty)$.

I have absolutely no idea what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint. Given $\epsilon = 1$ can you find a $delta$ that works at $x=10$? At $x=100$? At $x=1000$? Can you find one that works at any $x$?

Comment: Consider $f(x+\delta) - f(x)$. Is this expression bounded in $x$ for fixed $\delta$?

Comment: see tmy answer below

Answer (score 2):

**VERY SIMPLE TRICK**

Given $a>0$ if we take 
$$x = \frac{1}{a}+2 ~~~and  ~~~y = \frac{1}{a}+2+\frac{a}{2}  \color{red}{= x +\frac{a}{2}}
 $$ we have $$x,y\in [2,\infty)~~~ and~~~|x-y| =\frac{a}{2}<a $$

But since $ax = 1+ 2a$ we have

$$|f(x)-f(y)| =6 |y^2-x^2|= 6| x^2 + 2\frac{a}{2}x +\frac{a^2}{4} - x^2 |\\ = 6(ax +\frac{a^2}{4}) = 6(1+2a+\frac{a^2}{4} )>6$$

That is $$|f(x)-f(y)| >6$$

Thus $$\color{blue}{\exists \varepsilon_0 =6,\forall~a>0, \exists ~x,y\in [2,\infty): |x-y|< a~~and ~~|f(x)-f(y)|>6}$$

just take $$x = \frac{1}{a}+2 ~~~and  ~~~y = \frac{1}{a}+2+\frac{a}{2}  \color{red}{= x +\frac{a}{2}}
 $$

Answer (score 1):

$f:[2,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous if for every $\epsilon>0$ you can find some $\delta>0$ where any time there are $x,y\in [2,\infty)$ that satisfy $|x-y|<\delta$ you have $|6x^2-6y^2|<\epsilon$.

To show that this doesn't hold, you need to find some $\epsilon>0$ where there is no such $\delta>0$.

Say that you choose $\epsilon=1$. Is this possible? Choose some $y$ based on $\delta$ and $x$.