# Is Miura transformation invertible?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, integrable-systems

It is known that the KdV equation
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+b u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}=0\,,\quad b\in\mathbb{R}\,,
\end{align}
under the [Miura transformation](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/9/8/1202/234385/Korteweg-de-Vries-Equation-and-Generalizations-I-A?redirectedFrom=fulltext)
\begin{align}
v=\frac{3}{4b}\left(\frac{1}{4}u^2+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\,,
\end{align}
maps to equation
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{4b}\left(\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{3}{16}u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}\right)=0\,.
\end{align}
A solution to this system is that the MKdV equation, namely
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{3}{16}u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}=0\,,
\end{align}
must be fulfilled. Is Miura transformation $v=\frac{3}{4b}\left(\frac{1}{4}u^2+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$ invertible, i.e., can we obtain KdV from MKdV?

Answer (score 2):

### **Not a complete answer - just some thoughts.**

---

The Miura transformation is the mapping
$$u\mapsto \frac{3}{4b}\left(\frac{u^2}{4}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)=M[u]$$
To ask if the Miura transformation is invertible is to ask whether there is at most one solution $u$ to the equation
$$M[u]=v$$
This presents us with the "PDE" (really an ODE in disguise)
$$u^2/4+\partial_xu=\frac{4b}{3}v$$

Write this as
$$u'(x)=\frac{4b}{3}v(x)-\frac{{u(x)}^2}{4}\equiv F(x,u(x))$$
With of course
$$F(x,y):= \frac{4b}{3}v(x)-\frac{y^2}{4}$$
The question is, are solutions of this ODE necessarily unique given an appropriate initial condition $u(0)=u_0$?

The [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) tells us that a solution to this equation exists and is unique in some open interval provided that $F$ is continuous in its first argument and Lipschitz continuous in its second argument.

$F$ is continuous in its first argument as long as $v$ is continuous, which I think we are safe to just assume. However, $F$ is [**not** Lipschitz continuous in its second argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511972/fx-x2-is-not-lipschitz) , at least not on all of $\mathbb R$, and therefore, uniqueness of solutions cannot be guaranteed, again, at least not on all of $\mathbb R$.

*With that being said*, I haven't yet found a counterexample. But you could probably construct one if you tried hard enough.