# Show that $x^p$ is not uniformly continuous.

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

Show that $x^p$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, +\infty)$

I was able to show that it was continuous if $p \leq 1$, but I'm having trouble showing that it can't be uniformly continuous if $p > 1$.

Comment: $$(x+\epsilon)^p-x^p\geqslant(p-1)x^{p-1}\epsilon$$

Comment: You can easily adapt the accepted answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135234/showing-fx-x4-is-not-uniformly-continuous?rq=1